# Static Qt5 build on Linux: how to handle fonts when deploying?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, fonts

I have created static versions of Qt 5.2.0 libs with these configure options (Ubuntu 12.04):

> -opensource
>    -confirm-license
>    -force-pkg-config
>    -release
>    -static
>    -prefix '/home/juzzlin/qt5'
>    -no-icu
>    -opengl desktop
>    -no-glib
>    -accessibility
>    -nomake examples
>    -nomake tests
>    -qt-zlib
>    -qt-libpng
>    -qt-libjpeg
>    -qt-sql-sqlite
>    -qt-xcb
>    -qt-pcre
>    -v

Now, the problem is that when I have compiled and linked my app against these Qt libs, it tries to load fonts from the Qt installation path `/home/juzzlin/qt5/lib/fonts`. How is this supposed to work? The app works on the machine that I used to compile it, but not on some other machine. I also don't want to install Qt stuff to some system directories with the app, as applications shouldn't do that.

This is the error I get:

> QFontDatabase: Cannot find font directory /home/juzzlin/qt5/lib/fonts - is Qt installed correctly?

How can I force it to search for fonts in some other directory?

The other thing I don't understand is that why I don't have this same problem when cross-compiling for Windows with *MXE*? It uses practically the same configuring options when compiling Qt libs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can embed the font file(s) into your executable using the Qt resource system.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html

Then in your application, you can load the embedded font.

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQuickView view;

// Load the embedded font.
QString fontPath = ":/fonts/MyFont.ttf";
int fontId = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(fontPath);
if (fontId != -1)
{
    QFont font("MyFont");
    app.setFont(font);
}
```

I suspect that your application is searching for the fonts in your home directory because qmake hard-codes the paths to different resources at compile time. To see the values of these paths, run:

```
qmake -query
```

You can override these paths in your application by including a qt.conf file, which you can also embed into the executable using the qt resource system.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qt-conf.html

Comment: I didn't know about qt.conf, so thanks! :) This solves my problems.

Comment: However, I still don't understand why I don't have to worry about this if I use pre-compiled Qt libs and link dynamically or cross-compile for Windows using static libs. Why don't those libs search for font directory in some hard-coded location? It has always just worked. What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why, but I can speculate... I believe Qt 5 uses fontconfig to manage fonts and falls back to <qt5 install dir>/lib/fonts when that does not work. Perhaps there is a configuration option to tell Qt 5 to use fontconfig when using the xcb platform plugin.

Comment: It seems that installing libfontconfig1-dev and compiling Qt with -fontconfig solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you for `qmake -query`